# Is saying "But if I try I can't remember" good English?

Tags: british-english, australian-english

Is saying "But if I try I can't remember" good English?

I feel like there is something wrong with this sentence (apart from the use of "but" at the start of a sentence - it's a song lyric).

However, I can't put my finger on what is wrong with it. It uses the conditional "if" then a negative "can't". Maybe it is something to do with the use of "But"?

I think it would be better to say "Though I try I can't remember", but I am having difficulty justifying why this is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: tip 'o the tongue?

Answer (score 1):

First: anything goes in song lyrics...

I think it's the tense: *If I try I won't remember* sounds better to me. That would be because it is something happening in the (hypothetical) future, as you haven't tried it yet. But by using *can't* it no longer is marked as hypothetical, but definite.

In your second example, *though* is somewhat different, as it indicates that you have actually tried to remember, and failed. So *if* has an aspect of futurity in it, which *though* lacks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Starting a sentence with but isn't necessarily incorrect.

2) I think there is a difference in meaning between the lyric, and your suggested alternative.

If I try I cannot remember:

If I do not make an effort, it is likely that this knowledge will come to my mind. Or in any case, trying achieves nothing.

Though I try I can't remember:

Despite my best efforts, I am unable to remember.

---

As far as 'but if I try I can't remember', it makes perfect sense as a zero conditional.